# PUT/POST/DELETEメソッドURLの書式間違いや最後のスラッシュ忘れ対策方法

Tags: python3, django-rest-framework

以下のソースコードの動作において、
GETを除くそれぞれのメソッドは、適切なURL(http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/...)で最後にスラッシュがあれば、正常に呼び出されます。
しかし、スラッシュがない場合、
・DELETEの場合、retrieveが呼ばれます。
・POST,PUTの場合、エラーとなります。

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ 以降のどのような記述であっても、任意のエラーJSONレスポンスを返したいと考えていますが、どのようにしたらよいのでしょうか？

### ソースコード

```py
class TestAPIView(viewsets.ViewSet):
  def list(self, request):
    # [GET]
    ...
  def retrieve(self, request, pk):
    # [GET]/<pk>
    ...
  def create(self, request):
    #[POST]/
    ...
  def update(self, request, pk):
    #[PUT]/
    ...
  def delete(self, request, pk):
    #[DELETE]
    ...
```

Comment: 他の質問もそうですが、タイトルの頭に (既にタグ付けした) **単語をそのまま** 含めるのは不要です。以下のヘルプも参考にしてください。 ["タイトルにタグを使用してもいいのは、タイトルの会話的なトーンにとって本質的である場合のみです。"](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)